# Does the persistanceManager close automaticly when servlet is over?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I am currently developing for GAE using datastore and JDO. My question is simple, after I fetch an entity from the datastore and modify it (without using detach) I have to close the `persistanceManager` via `PersistanceManager.close()`. But what happen if I don't close it and the servlet is over and everything inside it get dispose? Doest the `persistanceManager` will close automatically? Or maybe it will leave an open connection with the entity?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [1], when the PersistenceManager is closed, only then the modification made on the object will reflect or updates the datastore.So thats why it is required to close the persistancemanager.

If you dont close the persistancemanager might be possible that your changes will not reflected or updated in the datastore.

[1] **Updating object with JDO:** https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Updating_an_Object

Answer (score 0):

How can it know its no longer of use? The publically available JDO spec says clearly enough that YOU have to close your PMs, just like you have to close your queries.